# Do we need to do both local sensitivity analysis and global sensitivity analysis?

Tags: statistics

Is there a reason why we need to do BOTH local SA and global SA when we want to determine the most influential parameters?

I am planning to do sensitivity analysis using normalised forward sensitivity index (local SA) and the LHS/PRCC approach (global SA). I am wondering, is one better than the other? Or just performing either one of it will suffice?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your study purpose. The local SA is mainly used to conduct parameter prioritization (which parameters are important to model output), but the global SA is used for parameter fixing (which parameters are "not" important to model output).

In a nutshell, if you have a metamodel with dozens of parameters that need to be calibrated with the advanced statistical approach (e.g., Bayesian), you might need to consider using global SA to find the non-influential parameters and fix them to improve the computational efficiency. Otherwise, you can just use local SA to investigate which parameters that dominate the model output.